# Releasing non-catkin Groovy packages through the build farm

Tags: ros, buildfarm, ros-groovy, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a collection of non-catkin packages (they form a stack in pre-Groovy terminology) for ROS Groovy that I would like to have built as Debian packages on the build farm.  Since these are not catkin packages, what set of instructions should I follow to make the release?  They will be hosted on Github.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58971/releasing-non-catkin-groovy-packages-through-the-build-farm/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will still use the older "release" package: http://ros.org/wiki/release

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-03-22**:
Thanks @fergs!